# Loading map in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, maps, mapkit

In my app i need a map to loaded by passing address,city, state province code and postal code.
Can any one tell me how can i do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below :-

```
  NSString* yourFullAddress = @"address,city, state province code and postal code";

    yourFullAddress =  [yourFullAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Now create the URL string ...
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@", yourFullAddress];

    // An the final magic ... openURL!
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Or in case u dont want to open google maps and rather set the coordinates on ur MKMapView ... u can GeoCode ur address to get the coordinates and finally set the coordinate region on ur MKMapview ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try searching on Google or SO?

A good start would be here http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/